# Why apollo client network request cancelled twice?

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo-client

My apollo/client - useQuery is loading twice which is normal based on normal flow but when I have my network tab on devtools open and noticed weird stuff.

I have 2 cancelled request I don't know why.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My code is identical to apollo client docs

```
function Dogs({ onDogSelected }) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DOGS);

  if (loading) return 'Loading...';
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

  return (
    <select name="dog" onChange={onDogSelected}>
      {data.dogs.map(dog => (
        <option key={dog.id} value={dog.breed}>
          {dog.breed}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

Anyone encountered this before?

Comment: We figured it out we have auth0 and nextjs ssr the grapql runs twice after each rendering.

Comment: Sounds like it's what i described in my answer below. In this case, can you mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your code in `_app.js` or wherever you instantiate the `apolloClient` is ran multiple times (at re-render), trashing the old client and creating a new one, and the current apollo calls (attached to the old instance) get cancelled then re-run once the newly created `apolloClient` is passed to the `ApolloProvider`.

The solution for this would be to make the `apolloClient` immutable and return the same instance unless the re-instantiation is necessary.

In my case, we had it set up like this:

```
_app.tsx:
const App = (props) => {
  const apolloClient = useApollo({ language, location });

  return (
     <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
       {...}
     </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

apollo-client.ts

WRONG WAY:
export default function useApollo(config) {
  return useMemo(() => createApolloClient(config), [config]);
}

GOOD WAY:
export default function useApollo() {
  return useMemo(() => createApolloClient(config), [config.language, config.location]);
}
```

Notice how useMemo doesn't do the job because it's comparing objects (references) which are always different.

This is only one thing to watch out for but there are many other reasons your `apolloClient` can get re-instantiated.