# Apollo consecutive calls are cancelled, possibly due to apolloClient reinstantiation

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

in my react code, I have the following hook and an onClick function:

```
const [getDataFromGraphql] = useGetDataFromGraphql();

const getData = async (...) => {
  const res = await getDataFromGraphql({ variables: { ... } });
  ...
}
```

where useGetDataFromGraphql is just another hook to call a lazy query

```
export default function useGetDataFromGraphql() {
  return useLazyQuery<..,..>(
    query,
    {
      client: aPrivateClient,
    }
  );
}
```

and `aPrivateClient` is an ApolloClient.

```
export default new ApolloClient({
  link: from([authLink, authExpiryLink, httpLink]),
  cache,
  defaultOptions,
});
```

I noticed that when I make several clicks of different buttons that call the same onClick function with different variables within a short period of time, every call except for the last call gets cancelled,  and the result from the last call replaces everything before, even though each onClick action would've each passed different variables.

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70741679/4756279) which made me try memoizing the Apollo Client, but that didn't help. The react app is connected to multiple clients, so we specify a client in the hook and the [example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/#step-4-connect-your-client-to-react) in the documentation with one client probably won't be applicable.

How can I restructure my setup so that consecutive network calls don't cancel anything out? And, if this is indeed the root cause, how do I make `ApolloClient` not re-instantiate?

Comment: think u need to create multiple instances of the hook, currently u are using the same hook for every button which makes apollo cancel all pending requests and fire a new request with the latest props

Comment: Check the info here - https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/5268. I thnik it will shine some light.

Answer (score 0):

The option we used in one of our previous project.
You could share the [Appolo Context](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/#step-4-connect-your-client-to-react) to other components as described in official docs.

In the enrty script:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
           <App/>
        </ApolloProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

The client itself example:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, splitLink]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

So in your other components you can do:

```
import {gql,useQuery} from '@apollo/client';
//...
const {loading,data:myData,refetch } = useQuery({your appolo query});
```

For the UI handlers it's better to use some UI librarires, i.e. [Antd Forms](https://ant.design/components/form). Then you can get control over states.